# BCMath code for converting Hex to Dec - Issues - A bug in code?

Tags: php, bcmath

I have some issue with a code trying to convert Hex values into decimal one. 
No matter if it is small or large integer, sometimes, the function returns me the Hex converted to Dec with 8 ceros as trailing.
For example: It should return 72500 and returns 72500.00000000
It is randomly and I think the code "is right".

**Good one:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [BlockHeight] => 7503088
    [BlockHeightHash] => 0x58daab46cb25e887985d8d22d735147a5d92a226316223de04dc7b0ae265f7a7
)
```

**Wrong one:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [BlockHeight] => 7503088.0000000000
    [BlockHeightHash] => 0x58daab46cb25e887985d8d22d735147a5d92a226316223de04dc7b0ae265f7a7
)
```

**Procedure**

```
public static function HexDec(string $hex)
{
    $dec = 0;
    $len = strlen($hex);
    for ($i = 1; $i <= $len; $i++)
    {
        $dec = bcadd($dec, bcmul(strval(hexdec($hex[$i - 1])), bcpow('16', strval($len - $i))));
    }
    //return (string)$dec;
    return $dec;
    //return sprintf('%.0F',$dec);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy way convert hex string to decimal string fro 32-bit version of php

```
$test = '0x7000005a00000ea5';
$rrrrr = gmp_strval($test);
var_dump($test, $rrrrr);
```

will return

> string '0x7000005a00000ea5' (length=18) 
> string '8070450918794989221' (length=19)